# Прототип объекта

Tags: javascript, прототипное-наследование

возьму цитату из учебника Кантора

> При выполнении new Object, создаваемому объекту ставится **proto** по
>   prototype конструктора, который в данном случае равен встроенному
>   Object.prototype.

Не понимаю - почему прототипом создаваемого объекта служит Object.prototype а не просто Object? Ведь prototype это свойство, а прототипом должен быть объект.

Comment: А что мешает свойству быть объектом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object` - это **функция-конструктор**.

У конструкторов есть специальное свойство *prototype*, которое используется для конструирования объекта.

Поэтому все вполне логично:

1. вызывается конструктор ( в данном случае *функция* Object )
2. создаваемому объекту устанавливается прототип из соответствующего поля конструктора.

Comment: Так а почему не просто __proto__ == Object, а __proto__ == Object.prototype?

Comment: @takecaretakecaretakecare, потому что `Object` - это **функция-конструктор**, а значение прототипа должно быть **объектом**.

Comment: Т.е я правильно понимаю - если в качестве прототипа используется обычный объект, то он и записывается в proto, а если функция-конструктор, которая не является сама объектом, то записывается ее св-то prototype, которое и является объектом, так?

Comment: @takecaretakecaretakecare, нет не правильно, в качестве прототипа используется **только** обычный объект. При этом, его можно установить вручную с помощью `setPrototypeOf`, или `Object.create`, либо он установится автоматически, при использовании конструктора, из поля `prototype`.

Comment: наконец то дошло! Благодарю

Answer (score 0):

Если вызов функции происходит с использование ключевого слова New, то интерпретатор создает пустой объект и передает его функции конструктору в качестве контекста. Это значит что этот пустой объект становится значением ключевого слова this внутри функции. После того как функция выполнит инициализацию свойств вновь созданного объекта, этот объект становится значением выражения создания объекта и в качества значения свойства prototype, вновь созданного объекта, устанавливается значение свойства prototype функции конструктора. Таковы правила создания объектов в языке JS